# Long.decode in Java 8 throwing NumberFormatException for valid number

Tags: java, java-8, decode, long-integer

In a Java 8 system, we are seeing a NumberFormatException thrown for what should be a valid string:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "86928"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:776)
        at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:928)
```

I am testing the code prior to this with a regular expression:

```
if(!values[51].isEmpty() && values[51].matches("^[0-9]*$")) {
    i.setMiles(Long.decode(values[51]));
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: you sure that is the place where it fails?

Comment: Could you add the code for the call and the initialization of the String?

Comment: looking at the code in Long.java:928 for jdk8 makes me suspect your original input (whatever is in values[51]) is not "86928". could you share whats in the original value?

Comment: @JGFMK no, you can use just the number string without the `L` for this. The code as posted works, so the issue is likely elsewhere

Comment: @DidierL damn, that is not obvious...

Comment: @Eugene using `decode() ` instead of `valueOf()` immediately felt strange to me. It's unfortunate that the exception does not contain the full original string.

Comment: @DidierL inheriting the “leading zero means octal” rule from C was unfortunate in general. Omitting the zero in the exception message is just maxing it out.

Comment: @Eugene, yes, due to company issues I didn't paste the rest of the stack trace.

Comment: Looking further up in the debug log, the value in values[51] is "086928" so, looking through the above comments, do you think Java is treating it as an Octal, and then failing on the 9 in the string?